# ld: building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, tvos, lto

I'm building a project (the target is a framework if it's important) for tvOS and getting the error from the linker:

> ld: building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

I ran `otool -l *.o` in `OBJECTS_FILE_DIR_normal` and figured out one of .o files is actually built for iOS instead of tvOS.

The problem is that there is no corresponding source file (*.mm or *.cpp) for that .o. It is called `<ProjectName>_lto.o` and I don't see any compiler invocations for that file in the build log. It appears only once in linker command line:

```
-Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Full/path/to/<ProjectName>.build/Debug-appletvos/tvOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/<ProjectName>_lto.o
```

`LLVM_LTO` build settings is not set explicitly, but it defaults to `NO`. Setting it to `NO` explicitly doesn't help.

I'm using Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002).

So my question is: why is this object file created at all and why is it created for wrong target platform?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this should be the answer to my own question or the edit, as it doesn't answer the original question "why that _lto.o file is generated at all for wrong arch with `LLVM_LTO=NO`", but it may help others troubleshoot this issue.

So I decided to try **enabling** LTO in the project. `LLVM_LTO=YES_THIN` behaved identically to `LLVM_LTO=NO`. `LLVM_LTO=YES` made linker produce tons of warnings like the following:

```
ld: warning: Linking two modules of different target triples: /path/to/one/of/3rdpary/libs/libproblematic.a(file1.o)' is 'arm64-apple-ios7.0.0' whereas 'ld-temp.o' is 'arm64-apple-tvos9.0.0'
ld: warning: Linking two modules of different target triples: /path/to/one/of/3rdpary/libs/libproblematic.a(file2.o)' is 'arm64-apple-ios7.0.0' whereas 'ld-temp.o' is 'arm64-apple-tvos9.0.0'
```

But with all those warnings for some weird reason the link succeeded. The interesting thing is that if I run `otool -l libproblematic.a`, I only see `cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_TVOS` lines and no `cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS` and linker didn't complain on any of the objects from that library that they were built for wrong target platform. Also `file1`, `file2`, etc. do not appear in the output of `otool -l libproblematic.a`.